# How to add custom exception/errors?

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I am would like to add errors or exception, which can show up on the cliet-side, when the user  leaves the username/password blank or press 'cancel' on the login dialog.  Currently, it shows a blank screen to those exception.

```
public class BasicAuthHandler : DelegatingHandler
 {
    private const string BasicAuthResponseHeader = "WWW-Authenticate";
    private const string BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue = "Basic";

    public BasicAuthHandler(iUser repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    [Inject]
    iUser repository { get; set; }


    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authValue = request.Headers.Authorization;


        if (authValue == null || authValue.Scheme != BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue)
        {
            return Unauthorized(request);
        }
        string[] credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authValue.Parameter)).Split(new[] { ':' });
        if (credentials.Length != 2 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[1]))
        {
            return Unauthorized(request);

        }
        api_login user = repository.Validate2(credentials[0], credentials[1]);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized(request);
        }
        string[] roles = new[] { "Users", "Testers" };
        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user.username, BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue), roles);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private Task<HttpResponseMessage> Unauthorized(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        response.Headers.Add(BasicAuthResponseHeader, BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue);
        var task = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        task.SetResult(response);
        return task.Task;
    }

    private api_login ParseAuthorizationHeader(string authHeader)
    {
        string[] credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader)).Split(new[] { ':' });
        if (credentials.Length != 2 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[1])) return null;

        return new api_login()
        {
            username = credentials[0],
            password = credentials[1],
        };
    }
```

Updated error code:

```
 protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authValue = request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (authValue == null || authValue.Scheme != BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue)
        {
            return Unauthorized(request);
        }

        string[] credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authValue.Parameter)).Split(new[] { ':' });
        if (credentials.Length != 2 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[1]))
        {
           //return Unauthorized(request);
           var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
           {
               Content = new StringContent(string.Format("access denied")),
           };
        }

        api_login user = repository.auth(credentials[0], credentials[1]);
        if (user == null)
        {
           //return Unauthorized(request);
           //return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "If not member, please sign in using:");
           var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
           {
               Content = new StringContent(string.Format("access denied")),
           };

        }

        var roles = repository.GetRolesForUser(user.username);
        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user.username, BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue), roles);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
       {
           var response = task.Result;

           if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
               && !response.Headers.Contains(BasicAuthResponseHeader))
           {
               // redirect to some log in page?
               var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
               {
                   Content = new StringContent(string.Format("access denied")),
               };
           }
           return response;
       });
    }
```

I am not sure on the right approach to go about adding exception to the code, I have added couple of error codes in the code above but whenever i press cancel on login dialog, it goes to blank screen instead of showing the following error messages.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You don't want to use exceptions. Just use an error message, error codes, or an object containing both.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for clarifying that up.  I would like to ask, if you could link an example where, I can start.  Would something like 'HttpStatusCode' work, its something I am currently researching and wanted to know, if I am on the right track.  Many thanks.

Comment: Rather than research it, I suggest you start writing code. It's the best way to learn both the right code to use, and which mistakes to not make.

Comment: Dear John, thank you for response and help.  I tried many approaches to get this to work, but I am still unable to get the error message to show on the client page, when the login dialog is left blank or incorrect user entry is inputted. if you get time, could provide some feedback to where I may be going wrong.  Many thanks